# What is the correct way to base a stage on a template when adding a new one to a Delivery Pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops, continuous-delivery

As a pipeline author I want to enhance the quality and speed up the process of adding more steps to a delivery pipeline by basing my new stage in the pipeline on a (preloaded) template. The template should hold the correct environment variables settings, jobs and input.

This should apply when I hit the plus sign of the Add Stage button.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently its not possible to load/apply a template using the "Add Stage" button in the Delivery Pipeline. Some alternative ways to accomplish it

- Have a template/reference stage in your Delivery Pipeline with all the environment properties. Clone new stages from this reference stage.
- Export your pipeline (with reference stage) as yaml and than use this pipeline.yaml for creating new pipelines. More information on exporting pipeline as yaml and using it in your project can be found here - [Delivery Pipeline Info](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/sharetextpipelines.html)